# What is the different that processing result?

Tags: c#, fileinfo

I compard to Code A and Code B.
Code B processed result to False at rare intervals.

what is the different???

Code A.

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(path1);

fi.CopyTo(path2, true);

FileInfo fi2 = new FileInfo(path2);

fi2.Exists;    // Always result "True"
```

Code B.

```
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(path1);

fi.CopyTo(path2, true).Exists;  // Result "false" at rare intervals
```

Help me!

Comment: Code A will return true only if File Exists. But the `fi.CopyTo(path2, true)` will depend if file is copied completely or not. So Code A is better.

Comment: You can just use `File.Exists(path2)`, in case you want to make code short

Comment: Most likely antivirus is involved and timing is key.

Comment: I agree with @LasseV.Karlsen . The source code in FileInfo does nearly exact the same in both cases. So it's very likely to be a timing issue with another software that is listening on file changes. (That could be something as Dropbox or OneDrive as well as an antivirus.

Comment: `The Exists property returns false if any error occurs while trying to determine if the specified file exists. This can occur in situations that raise exceptions such as passing a file name with invalid characters or too many characters, a failing or missing disk, or if the caller does not have permission to read the file.` So normally it may occur in both cases. Otherwise a Refresh() could help cause FileInfo provides only snapshot information